# How to get text in html textbox using aspx c# and display it

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I need to create login + sign up forms using aspx files.

I decided to make it one page 2 forms style that changes the form on a button press. Now I need to display the entered username after pressing the submit button in a new page.

This is the HTML:

```
    <%--Register--%>
    <section>
        <div id="container_demo">
            <!-- hidden anchor to stop jump -->
            <a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister"></a>
            <a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="login" class="animate form">
                    <form  autocomplete="on" runat="server" name="signin" method="post" id="signin">
                        <h1>התחבר</h1>
                        <p>
                            <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u">אימייל או שם משתמש: </label>
                            <input <%--id="username"--%> id="signUsername" required="required" type="text" placeholder="myusername or mymail@mail.com" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">סיסמה : </label>
                            <input id="lPassword" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="keeplogin">
                            <label for="loginkeeping">השאר אותי מחובר</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" value="loginkeeping" />

                        </p>
                        <p class="login button">
                            <input type="submit" value="התחבר" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="change_link">
                            אין משתמש?
                                <a href="#toregister" class="to_register">הצטרף</a>
                        </p>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div id="register" class="animate form">
                    <form action="mysuperscript.php" autocomplete="on" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
                        <h1>הירשם </h1>
                        <p>
                            <label for="usernamesignup" <%--class="uname"--%> data-icon="u">שם משתמש</label>
                            <input id="usernamesignup" name="loginUsername" required="required" type="text" placeholder="mysuperusername690" pattern=".{3,}" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('שם משתמש קצר')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="fNmae" class="fname" data-icon="u">שם פרטי</label>
                            <input id="fName" class="fnamesign" required="required" type="text" placeholder="איציק" />

                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="lName" class=" lNaem" data-icon="u">שם משפחה</label>
                            <input id="lName" class="lNamesign" required="required" type="text" placeholder="פלדמן" />

                        </p>

                        <p>
                            <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e">אימייל</label>
                            <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email" placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="Password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">סיסמה </label>
                            <input id="Password" name="passwordsignup" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="cPassword" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">אשר סיסמה </label>
                            <input id="cPassword" name="passwordsignup_confirm" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" />

                        </p>


                        <label for="bday">יום הולדת</label>
                        <p id="birthday">
                            <select name='day' id='dayddl'>
                                <option value='1'>1</option>
                                <option value='2'>2</option>
                                <option value='3'>3</option>
                                <option value='4'>4</option>
                                <option value='5'>5</option>
                                <option value='6'>6</option>
                                <option value='7'>7</option>
                                <option value='8'>8</option>
                                <option value='9'>9</option>
                                <option value='10'>10</option>
                                <option value='11'>11</option>
                                <option value='12'>12</option>
                                <option value='13'>13</option>
                                <option value='14'>14</option>
                                <option value='15'>15</option>
                                <option value='16'>16</option>
                                <option value='17'>17</option>
                                <option value='18'>18</option>
                                <option value='19'>19</option>
                                <option value='20'>20</option>
                                <option value='21'>21</option>
                                <option value='22'>22</option>
                                <option value='23'>23</option>
                                <option value='24'>24</option>
                                <option value='25'>25</option>
                                <option value='26'>26</option>
                                <option value='27'>27</option>
                                <option value='28'>28</option>
                                <option value='29'>29</option>
                                <option value='30'>30</option>
                                <option value='31'>31</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name='month' id='monthddl'>
                                <option value='1'>ינואר</option>
                                <option value='2'>פבואר</option>
                                <option value='3'>מרץ</option>
                                <option value='4'>אפריל</option>
                                <option value='5'>מאי</option>
                                <option value='6'>יוני</option>
                                <option value='7'>יולי</option>
                                <option value='8'>אוגוסט</option>
                                <option value='9'>ספטמבר</option>
                                <option value='10'>אוקטובר</option>
                                <option value='11'>נובמבר</option>
                                <option value='12'>דצמבר</option>
                            </select>


                            <input id="byear" name="byear" required="required" type="number" placeholder="2016" min="1970" max="2016" />


                        </p>

                        <p id="tel">
                            <label for="phone">מספר טלפון</label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="text" maxlength="3" id="phone" placeholder="050" class="bphone" />
                            -
                                <input type="text" maxlength="7" placeholder="1234567" class="ephone" />

                        </p>

                        <div id="mof">
                            <p>
                                <label for="gedner">מין</label>
                                <br />
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked />זכר
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />נקבה
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>סגנון האהוב</label>
                                <br />
                                <input type="radio" name="style" value="rock" required="required" />רוק
                                <br />
                                <input type="radio" name="style" value="metal" required="required" />מאטל
                                <br />
                                <input type="radio" name="style" value="classic" required="required" />
                                קלאסי
                                <br />
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <p class="signin button">
                            <input type="submit" value="הירשם" id="sub" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="change_link">
                            יש משתמש ?
                                <a href="#tologin" class="to_register" id="reLogin">התחבר </a>
                        </p>


                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

And this the .cs file:

```
public partial class Login_N_register_ : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string st = "";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Signin vars
        string signUser = ((TextBox)signin.FindControl("signUsername")).Text;
        //Login vars
        string loginUser = Request.Form["loginUsername"];
     
            st +="<h3 style='postition:absolute;top:50%;z-index:999;'>"+ signUser+"</h3>";
       
    }
}
```

For some reason the .cs file won't show the entered text.

Didn't get to it because I want to make one form to work but because it's a 2 form one page I need it to only display the textbox which is on the page.

For example:

I log in as: x: nothing that relates to the signup form won't run and after pressing submit the .cs file add it to MasterPage code and I will be transferred to a new page (action="Main.master" I think).

And the other way around.

Comment: Can't you just call Request.Form["signUsername"] to access the submitted value, rather than the unusual casting to TextBox and then getting its Text property?

Comment: Yea I did it, the text property is another failed attempt couldn't get both of the versions to work

Comment: Capture the forms onsubmit event and see what the form values are prior to submission suppressing the submission with a false return. Then check what's in the form submission by re-enabling it. You need to ensure that the client side is correctly submitting the data first. If it's definitely being submitted by the client along with the other values, then check that other values are coming in server side as well.

Comment: You just added it to st, a class variable, that will do nothing, set it to the textbox.

Comment: @ManoDestra you mean to create something like if(random textobx name =! null){ return true}?

Comment: @Gusman not sure if I fully understood you but if I did I dont want to change the textbox I want to change the page

Comment: Ok, then you need to modify the page's content, it should be done using an HtmlLiteral control or just hidding/showing controls, it's the easiest way. Adding an string to a local variable will not modify anything.

Comment: Check the client side submission first e.g. `<form onsubmit="return checkForm();">`. Then simply write a checkForm() JavaScript function that returns false for the time being. And in that function, loop through the form's inputs and output their values to the console. This way, you can see what is about to be submitted. Then, you can get it to return true and it will submit the form this time. Then, you can check the values coming in server side to be sure what actually arrived server side.

Comment: Yeah, if you need to change the UI, then change the UI. Don't write custom HTML server side. That's not generally a good idea.

Comment: @ManoDestra I wish I could but as I said it's for a school project and my teacher is not the nicest person and she want to use c# and im not sure how to you can use JS to change things on the master page after submitting form and then open a different page. The UI change is not on the some page but a different one

Comment: You're not doing anything fancy with JavaScript here. It's basic HTML event handling. I'm merely asking you to handle the form's onsubmit event, so that you can debug what you are submitting to the server from the client. The return value that you return from your function dictates whether the form will submit or not: false prevents submission, true allows submission to continue. So, you can debug what values are being submitted first, then you can check the server side to ensure that those values came through. I'm trying to show you how to debug it successfully here.

Comment: Just tested it and the value of the textbox does pass through